# opera search bar: enter doesn't search

Tags: keyboard, opera-browser

I write my question in a search box (on stack exchange or wikipedia or Google.) when I press enter, it doesn't search.

This isn't a keyboard thing since I've tried swiftkey, android keyboard, Samsung keyboard, and swype.

It is an opera thing, since using default browser, the keyboard "enter" is replaced by a spyglass for search or a tick in a circle for "go" as expected. 
I've not tried any other browsers.

I only noticed this problem after upgrading my galaxy tab to 3.2...

Comment: There is no opera tag and I can't create one...

Comment: There is no `opera` tag because we have an `opera-mini` tag and an `opera-mobile` tag. There are some distinct differences between Mini and Mobile. Which are you using?

Comment: Aha. I can't see the autocomplete options when typing on my galaxy tab... Opera mobile, and I'm using.

Comment: You should see autocomplete options in the mobile view, with Opera mobile -- but there's a delay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A software update fixed this problem. Must've been a bug in opera mobile.

Answer (score 1):

My solution for SO uses an undocumented feature (an easy trick when there's no documentation whatsoever): longtouch the search bar, add it as a search engine, and then use Opera's own search bar for such sites.  A trick you may like with SO is to do this multiple times, then manage search engines, click on one of the SO 'engines', and modify it so that you can readily add e.g. `[android]` to your searches.  It may feel like a workaround, but the result is more comfortable than what I was used to on desktop systems.